# Changing the value of a property name in a tag with DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm not really sure what I'm doing incorrectly here. The question asks us to Set the href attribute of the a tag to https://www.zybooks.com/.

This is the given tag `<a href = "https://www.example.org>Link</a>`

Here is my answer:

```
var x;
x = document.getElementsByTagName("a").href = "https://www.zybooks.com/";
```

The following error is given:

Testing the value of the href attribute
Yours and expected differ. See highlights below.
Yours
https://www.example.org/
Expected
https://www.zybooks.com/

I'm not sure why this is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `getElementsByTagName` returns **a list** of DOM elements, not just one!

So, simply accessing the list's first element with `[0]` should do the trick:

```
x = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href = "https://www.zybooks.com/";
```

**Edit:** This answer just shows what was wrong in the OP's original code. As the comments say, using `getElementsByTagName('a')[0]` is definitely not the best approach; using `querySelector("a")` would be a better way to do it.

Comment: Thank you. This was correct. How would you access that element without using getElementsByTagName since there is no given ID in the tag? In other words, is there a way to access it without having [0] as part of the solution since it returns a list?

Comment: @trenz You can use `document.querySelector('a')`. This function takes regular CSS selectors and returns the first element that is a match.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I was just explaining what was wrong in the OP's statement, not saying this is the best approach. `querySelector` is a **much** better way to go indeed.

Comment: The longer the programming community continues to show inline scripting and the use of legacy API's, the longer we'll have to continue to answer these kinds of questions. The real answer here is "Your approaching this incorrectly. Here's the correct way to do it."